# Youtube Authentication Exception on the Server

Tags: authentication, youtube

I have to access uploaded videos on you tube.In the code I am authenticating the user is going to access the account.

```
var settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("XYZ", "ABC",     
                  "xxx@gmail.com", "pwd");

var request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

var service = new YouTubeService("XYZ");

service.setUserCredentials("xxx@gmail.com", "pwd");
var token = service.QueryClientLoginToken();
service.SetAuthenticationToken(token);

Uri uri = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(uri);

VideoUrlList = new List<VideoInformation>();
foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
{
    VideoUrlList.Add(new VideoInformation
    {
        VideoId = entry.VideoId,
        VideoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + entry.VideoId
    });
}
```

The code I am using in local environment is running well. But the same code producing the authentication exception on the server.

"The Server responded with a status of 500(Internal server Error)"

Can any body suggest me how to resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The detailed exception is :[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8527068
   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() +147